# Howt to tell emacs VC that I want a file to be managed by git not by svn when the file is under both version systems?

Tags: svn, git, emacs

I was using until now emacs21 with git.el, so it was not a problem but now with emacs22 git management is integrated in VC so I manage my git files with vc-git. That is ok when the files are only manged by git. I can see a `GIT-master` in the status. But when I am editing files managed by both svn (for the stable commits and group VC) and git (for my own and in-between commits) I don't know how to force the commits to be done with git (the status say that is a svn file). Any idea?

I can always use the `M-! git status` `M-! git add` etc but having the VC shortcuts and integrating the diff in emacs is very nice.

note: I am not using git-svn at the moemnt. This is an already svn branch checkout that I want to have some experimental changes been controlled by git until the code becomes stable, instead of doing a svn sub-branch. I believe that the git-svn would be the way to go but unfortunately I need to find the time to read about it and install whatever is needed. So I am using what I already know that is simple git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `vc-handled-backends` and move Git above Subversion.  You should really just try using `git-svn` though; you can use `git rebase -i` or `git merge --squash` to collapse (squash) a bunch of Git changesets into a single Subversion revision.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I really should try git-svn. It has been in my todo list for long time. But now all my projects are in git except one in SVN and other two in CVS. So nothing is pushing me hard to spent time reading about the git-svn.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it could help you but I change VC backend between SVN and Git with `C-x v b` or `M-x vc-switch-backend` for a file tracked by both repos.