# Change emacs version control mode

Tags: git, svn, version-control, emacs

I have a `file.txt` that is tracked by both SVN and Git. The directory structure looks like this:

```
  + prj/
  |
  +    .git/
  +    src/
  |        .svn/
  |        file.txt
```

When I open that file in Emacs, it opens in SVN mode by default. How do I change it to open in Git mode? None of the `vc-` commands contain something to change version-control mode.

EDIT: I would like to switch between SVN and Git modes on a file-by-file basis. A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059804/howt-to-tell-emacs-vc-that-i-want-a-file-to-be-managed-by-git-not-by-svn-when-th?rq=1) doesn't answer how to do it. `vc-handled-backends` changes the order permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time ago I used `C-x v b` (for `vc-switch-backend`) to deal with files that were both in RCS and CVS.  I guess that should work for modern version control systems as well.